# Closure disable URL substitution with autoescape=strict

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-closure, google-closure-templates, soy-templates

I am rendering a soy template using Closure for a chrome extension and am having trouble inserting `chrome-extension://*` links since they are being filtered by `soy.$$filterNormalizeUri`

While normally it would be undesirable to allow `chrome-extension://*` links, it makes sense within a chrome extension.

Is there a way to whitelist the protocol or allow a particular case of unfiltered URL substitution (perhaps using `soy.$$normalizeUri` instead of `soy.$$filterNormalizeUri`)?  The input is not user-defined and should be safe for consumption.

Example:

```
{template .t}
  {foreach $src in $list}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$src}" />
  {/foreach}
{/template}
```

Where `$list` is a generated list of stylesheet paths beginning with `chrome-extension://*`

The error returned is `Uncaught AssertionError: Failure: Bad value`chrome-extension://...`for |filterNormalizeUri`

Info about escaping: https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/security#in_urls

Answer (score 0):

If the elements of $list are SanitizedContent instances instead of strings, then I think they should not be escaped.